# Custom constructor as a simple method

Tags: java, android

I have a class called `Screen`. Each time I want to set a new Screen in my application, I call the following method:

```
public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if(this.screen != null) {
            this.screen.pause();
            this.screen.onDispose();

        }
        this.getGraphics().drawColor(Color.BLACK); // Clear virtual framebuffer
        this.screen = screen;
        this.screen.load();
        this.screen.resume(); 
        WSLog.e(Game.GAME_ENGINE_TAG, this, "New Screen has been created");
}
```

Now my question is: Is it permissible to replace the constructor's function with a `load` method?

I'm doing this, because when setting a new screen, the current one has to be disposed first and then the new one can be loaded, however if I do all the loading in the constructor, then the new screen would initialize first and then the current one would be diposed (which is not ideal).

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly valid and you are not replacing the constructor at all. The main role of a `constructor` is to initialize variables putting the object in a valid state for use. However, that doesn't mean the object has to fulfill all of it's responsabilities right away. Let's say you have designed an `Engine` class. Calling it's constructor doesn't necessary implies starting the engine right away. There would be nothing wrong about having a `start` method allowing to start the engine after the object instance have been created.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely permissible. 
When you use Window Forms in C#, there is a method called InitializeComponents() that is used to set up all the objects and events of the form. Your scenario is valid because like you said, there are times when you wouldn't want to do it.

A Constructor is used for initializing variables and/or allocating space at a minimum. Don't be afraid to put more of your code into other methods, especially if you can envision times when you wouldn't want to use a piece of code. It makes your program more flexible.

Good Luck :)